# while moving to a new server, is it ok to create system accounts?

Tags: filesystem, migration

I should move all the data, installations from server A to server B. Both are Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

There is a much-used instruction set [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/). One thing I don't understand is

```
You should never ever create any new system user accounts on the
newly installed Cent OS Linux.
```

Why is this? Does it apply to Ubuntu as well? If I need my system to be as identical as possible, what should I do with system accounts, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package which depends on a system account is also responsible for setting up the account.  For example, `www-data` is created by any HTTPD server when you install it.  Doing it manually is redundant and has a high potential for messing up the standard defaults which are required for the account in question.

Comment: ...assuming things are installed from packages, not all of the things we have, are. So for those I need to create them myself. Thank you!

Comment: Though then it might make sense to create a private package for that, just to unify the installation process and ease of migration. (If you don't do this a lot, it may not be worth it, though many services can easily be packaged.)